# webpack resolve default import to named import

Tags: webpack

I have an app bundled with external dependency

```
externals: {
    test: 'Test'
}
```

When i import with

```
import { Component1 } from 'test';
```

The application webpack compilation ignores bundling the Component1 and refers to the external bundle.

When i import with

```
import Component1 from 'test/Component1';
```

webpack considers only the **'test'** as external bundle, it is bundling the Component1 implementation and its dependency along with the application bundle.

i was trying with resolve in webpack config.

is there any way translate **'test/*'** to a named import before compilation starts.